# Why do I get different results when calling JValue.ToString() and JValue.ToString(Formatting.None)?

Tags: c#, json.net

Example code with Newtonsoft.Json:

```
JValue v = new JValue("abc");
var vString = v.ToString();  // <= returns "abc"
var vStringWithFormatting = v.ToString(Formatting.None); // returns "\"abc\""
```

**v.ToString()** returns the string as I expect it. **v.ToString(Formatting.None)** returns it with double quotes around it. Why?

I looked into the Newtonsoft.Json code on Github and found this:

- **JToken** implements **ToString()** and **ToString(Formatting)**. **ToString()** internally calls **ToString(Formatting.Indented)**, so I expect that those two are supposed to return the same result. Both seem to return "\"abc\"".
- **JValue** overrides **ToString()** and returns "abc". But it does ***not*** override **ToString(Formatting)**. So the latter one takes the implementation of **JToken** and returns "\"abc\"".

Is that what should happen?

Background: I'm, working on some rather generic code that deals with different kinds of `JSON` objects. At one point I have the value of a `JProperty`, which can be a `JValue`, a `JArray`, or a `JObject`. I need the string representation of that, so I'm using `.ToString()` on it. Recently I decided to use the compact representation, so I changed that to `.ToString(Formatting.None)` and suddenly my tests fail. Now I have to add a type check for `JValue` and use `ToString()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to make sense of the behavior as provided by the interface, not by the actual implementation that you have consulted. You can (of course) do this in times of open source but relying on one method's particular implementation because of this detailed knowledge does't sound right to me.

*v.ToString()* binds to *JValue*'s method

```
public override string ToString();
```

Let's see: if I want to work with a string value from a parsed JSON than what I need inside C# is a C#-string, right? A C#-string reads "abc", not "\"abc\"". Therefore, it works as expected (and as designed) for me.

```
v.ToString(Formatting.None)
```

binds to *JValue*'s

```
public string ToString(Formatting formatting, params JsonConverter[] converters);
```

In my version (Json.Net 9 beta) the second method returns the string enclosed in quotation marks, no matter if *Formatting* is *Formatting.Indented* or *Formatting.None*.

Let's see if this makes sense: if I'm concerned about formatting (newline before and after brackets/commas, and indention), I am probably writing some JSON code into a stream that is meant to be read by a human or **parsed** by whatever language later, JS or C# for example or in this context here by Json.Net doing sth like

```
var abc = JValue.Parse("\"abc\"");
```

(which would show in a file as just **"abc"**). Therefore, the second *ToString* method with the Formatting parameter is meant for a different purpose. And again: it works as expected (and as designed) imho.

Comment: Okay, I'm still confused by this behavior. And it triggered an error in my code because of that unexpected behavior, which was luckily detected by unit tests. Personally, I still think that `ToString()` should do the same as `ToString(Formatting.Indented)` in _all_ cases, and not only for some specific sub classes of `JToken`. However, I didn't expect a change in the behavior, because that would be a potential regression. Maybe some code relies on that specific behavior. I guess I have to live with that :)